# ¿Por qué nunca aparecen preguntas de SOes en la sección 'Preguntas populares en la red'?

Tags: discusión, stackexchange

Con la 'graduación' del sitio suponía, erróneamente, que comenzarían a aparecer preguntas de SOes en la sección 'Preguntas populares en la red' pero nunca sucedió (aunque luego caí en cuenta que los sitios en beta sí aparecen de vez en cuando) ¿Existe alguna razón para esto?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Según entiendo la [respuesta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272752/289691) a [es.SO questions aren't excluded from the Hot Questions list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271194/289691), SO.es fue retirado de la lista de sitios a ser incluido en "Preguntas populares en la red". El motivo es que la mayoría de los sitios de Stack Exchange son en inglés y muy pocos de los miembros hablan español o cualquiera de los otros idiomas de los sitios internacionales.

Comment: Exactamente. Somos minoría en cuanto a lenguaje así que se prefiere mantener esa sección en inglés al igual que los otros sitios de la red (al excluir los sitios internacionales).

Comment: En SOes somos minoría, pero en general [somos mayoría](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_languages_by_number_of_native_speakers) superando al inglés y siendo superados solo por el chino mandarín. Y el trato recibido nos lleva a ser continuar como minoría.